# Java: Google Spreadsheet API & Uploading csv file?

Tags: java, google-docs-api

How can I upload a csv file on my computer programmaticaly using Google Spreadsheet API?

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingDocumentOrFileWithContentOnly

Is there a sample Java code anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [example code](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html#UploadDocToAFolder) for this.  There is also a guide to [installing](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html) the library.  I don't know if you really need all those dependencies.